# Can an app change its name if the user subsribes from a free to purchased version?

Tags: ios, app-store

If a user downloads an app which offers a free trial or lite version etc. of an app and then they want to upgrade to a paid/subscribed version (which is actually the same app, not two separate apps) then is it possible for the name of the app to change from i.e "ABC trial" to "ABC"?

Comment: No. (Consider the fact that the app name, etc. is a part of the code-signed deliverable, how would this be possible?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do this if you're using In App Purchasing to upgrade app since app bundle is read-only and you can't change app name.

The only thing you can do is to create separate "full" app and place link to it in your free app.